# Device emulator-5554 disconnected (with no Emulators on Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I get an error while trying to run any app on a physical device.

Device emulator-5554disconnected, monitoring stopped.
Error while Installing APK

It works after trying at least 3 times, but sometimes it gets frustrating.

I tried to delete all the emulators and reinstall Android Studio but it didn't help. and the set deployment target is always flashing like so:

[flashing emulator error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/792v6.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the suggestion but it didn't work, after a few days of work on it, I found out that a vpn software (SoftEther) that I had installed was causing the problem, uninstalling it solved everything. 
it seems adb was interfering with a network bridge the software was trying to create.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it looks like Docker interferes with adb.

I tried restarting Android Studio, `adb kill-server && adb start-server`, and anything else I could think of.

Then I tried killing all docker containers <s>and quitting the docker app</s>, and everything works nicely again! Edit: Killing the containers is enough

I'm wondering if this is a newly introduced issue in Android Studio/adb/Docker - I updated to AS 3.4 recently, and I don't remember having this problem in the past, but it could have just been a coincidence.

Comment: Same here. I didn't have this problem until Android Studio 3.3. Stopping all running Docker containers resolved it. I didn't have to stop the Docker service itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the adb.
Use the following command to restart adb

```
adb -d kill-server && adb -d start-server
```

Use command -d for real device and command -e for emulator in case both are connected

Also if that doesnot work clean the project and reset connected emulator. 
Run Emulator and wait for the home screen of the Emulator to load

```
Click Window > Open Perspective > DDMS
In Devices Panel, click on drop down menu > Reset adb
Run project
```